# Python pandas data frame code optimisation

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am actually looking to optimize my code here in python. I'm hitting my ES(elastic search) and getting json response, now i'm iterating over json response and storing them as list to append them as column in dataframe

```
unmtchd_ESdata={"Response from Elastic seaach"}

    for i in range(len(unmtchd_ESdata['aggregations']['filtered']['POSCode']['buckets'])):
        list6.append(unmtchd_ESdata['avg'])
        list7.append(unmtchd_ESdata['key'])
        ....
        ....

    mkt_df=pd.DataFrame()
    mkt_df["market_avg_total_sales_count"]=dict6
    mkt_df["pos_code"]=dict7
    ...
    ....
```

At the end the result will have mkt_df dataframe with all the columns being assigned with values in the order of what was appended to the list. If a list suppose list6 is appended with values like [01200000129,00980030003] then it wil be present in the below form in data format and same applies for the rest as well

```
   market_avg_total_sales_count     pos_code 
0                        329.75  01200000129 
1                         15.00  00980030003
```

Now my question here is i'm reading too many variables and i want them as dataframe values and obviously having N number of list is making my program in efficient because all these operations are in memory.
Any suggestions on how to replicate such scenerio with less space and time complexity

Edit:
Adding my json structure here :

```
{
  "took": 28,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 12170,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "filtered": {
      "doc_count": 5,
      "POSCode": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
          {
            "key": "01200000129",
            "doc_count": 4,
            "POSCodeModifier": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key": "0",
                  "doc_count": 4,
                  "CSP": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                      {
                        "key": "5555",
                        "doc_count": 4,
                        "per_stock": {
                          "buckets": [
                            {
                              "key_as_string": "2018-02-26",
                              "key": 1519603200000,
                              "doc_count": 0,
                              "avg_week_qty_sales": {
                                "value": 0
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "key_as_string": "2018-03-05",
                              "key": 1520208000000,
                              "doc_count": 1,
                              "avg_week_qty_sales": {
                                "value": 10
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "key_as_string": "2018-03-12",
                              "key": 1520812800000,
                              "doc_count": 1,
                              "avg_week_qty_sales": {
                                "value": 300
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "key_as_string": "2018-03-19",
                              "key": 1521417600000,
                              "doc_count": 1,
                              "avg_week_qty_sales": {
                                "value": 1000
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "key_as_string": "2018-03-26",
                              "key": 1522022400000,
                              "doc_count": 1,
                              "avg_week_qty_sales": {
                                "value": 9
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "market_week_metrics": {
                          "count": 4,
                          "min": 9,
                          "max": 1000,
                          "avg": 329.75,
                          "sum": 1319,
                          "sum_of_squares": 1090181,
                          "variance": 163810.1875,
                          "std_deviation": 404.7347124969639,
                          "std_deviation_bounds": {
                            "upper": 1139.2194249939278,
                            "lower": -479.71942499392776
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "00980030003",
            "doc_count": 1,
            "POSCodeModifier": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
              "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
              "buckets": [
                {
                  "key": "0",
                  "doc_count": 1,
                  "CSP": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [
                      {
                        "key": "5555",
                        "doc_count": 1,
                        "per_stock": {
                          "buckets": [
                            {
                              "key_as_string": "2018-02-26",
                              "key": 1519603200000,
                              "doc_count": 0,
                              "avg_week_qty_sales": {
                                "value": 0
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "key_as_string": "2018-03-05",
                              "key": 1520208000000,
                              "doc_count": 1,
                              "avg_week_qty_sales": {
                                "value": 15
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "key_as_string": "2018-03-12",
                              "key": 1520812800000,
                              "doc_count": 0,
                              "avg_week_qty_sales": {
                                "value": 0
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "key_as_string": "2018-03-19",
                              "key": 1521417600000,
                              "doc_count": 0,
                              "avg_week_qty_sales": {
                                "value": 0
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "key_as_string": "2018-03-26",
                              "key": 1522022400000,
                              "doc_count": 0,
                              "avg_week_qty_sales": {
                                "value": 0
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "market_week_metrics": {
                          "count": 1,
                          "min": 15,
                          "max": 15,
                          "avg": 15,
                          "sum": 15,
                          "sum_of_squares": 225,
                          "variance": 0,
                          "std_deviation": 0,
                          "std_deviation_bounds": {
                            "upper": 15,
                            "lower": 15
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The values that i'm trying to fetch

```
for i in range(len(unmtchd_ESdata['aggregations']['filtered']['POSCode']['buckets'])):
            list6.append(unmtchd_ESdata['aggregations']['filtered']['POSCode']['buckets'][i]['POSCodeModifier']['buckets'][0]['CSP']['buckets'][0]['market_week_metrics']['avg'])
            list7.append(unmtchd_ESdata['aggregations']['filtered']['POSCode']['buckets'][i]['key'])
            list8.append(unmtchd_ESdata['aggregations']['filtered']['POSCode']['buckets'][i]['POSCodeModifier']['buckets'][0]['CSP']['buckets'][0]['market_week_metrics']['max']-unmtchd_ESdata['aggregations']['filtered']['POSCode']['buckets'][i]['POSCodeModifier']['buckets'][0]['CSP']['buckets'][0]['market_week_metrics']['min'])
            list9.append(unmtchd_ESdata['aggregations']['filtered']['POSCode']['buckets'][i]['POSCodeModifier']['buckets'][0]['CSP']['buckets'][0]['market_week_metrics']['max'])
            list10.append(unmtchd_ESdata['aggregations']['filtered']['POSCode']['buckets'][i]['POSCodeModifier']['buckets'][0]['CSP']['buckets'][0]['market_week_metrics']['min'])
```

Comment: I have a feeling that the slow bit is the sequential list appends, *not* the dataframe series constructions. Are you *sure* that the bottleneck is in assigning `pandas` series from lists?

Comment: Even i have a feeling "slow bit is the sequential list appends" because i'm using around 20 such appends in my code.

Comment: In that case, you might have to show us some of the json. Not all 20 keys and all rows, maybe 4 keys for 4 rows is enough. Then we can suggest a better way for you to build your dataframe.

Comment: Added you can have a look @jpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create just one list and append a tuple with `n` dim, where `n` is the number of cols, each iteration, for example:

```
for i in range(3):
    some_list.append((i, i+3))
```

Results:

```
[(0, 3), (1, 4), (2, 5)]
```

Passing it to a dataframe gives:

```
pd.DataFrame(some_list, columns=['col1', 'col2'])
   col1  col2
0     0     3
1     1     4
2     2     5
```

Try to adapt it to your solution.

Comment: kudos! You saved me from using some extra space